# Matplotlib X axis DateTime - bring data together

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I do a plot with matplotlib like that:

```
    # axis is a figure.subplot 
    axis.plot(df["DateTime"], df["yvalues"]) 
    axis.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m %H:%M'))
```

And result like the
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf5lo.png)

However I want to see the data closely with the correct x axis ticks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
#ticks option takes a list of x-axis tick locations.
tick_vals = ['2020-02-01','2020-03-01','2020-04-01']

#minor option takes Boolean that sets major ticks if False, sets Minor if True (False is default)
minor_option = False : bool, optional

import numpy as np

axes.set_xticks(ticks = tick_vals, minor=minor_option)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set:

```
    axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.AutoLocator())
    axes.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.AutoMinorLocator())
```

It will work properly.